# 'account_tags' is not a valid tag library

Tags: python, django

I'm working on designing a web page in Python/Django, and when I try to run my program's server, I get an error message stating:

```
TemplateServerError:
'account_tags' is not a valid tag library: Template library account_tags not found, tried django.templatetags.account_tags,django.contrib.admin.templatetags.account_tags,django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.account_tags,django_forms_bootstrap.templatetags.account_tags,pinax_theme_bootstrap.templatetags.account_tags,pinax_theme_foundation.templatetags.account_tags,bootstrapform.templatetags.account_tags,metron.templatetags.account_tags
```

The problem comes from this line of code:

```
{% load account_tags %}
```

Does anyone know what else I can install to obtain the correct 'account_tags' library? Thanks!

Comment: Check if you have an `__init__.py` file in the same directory where your tags file lives. Also make sure to add the app which contains these tags to `INSTALLED_APPS` in your settings file.

Comment: A quick search for 'django account_tags' suggests that the libary might be from [django-user-accounts](https://github.com/pinax/django-user-accounts).

Comment: @Alasdair, I already have django-user-accounts installed on my machine, but for some reason when I try to add it to my INSTALLED_APPS, it keeps saying "module not found". Is there just some weird way to format django-user-accounts in INSTALLED_APPS? Because I've tried 'django-user-accounts' and 'django_user_accounts', and neither worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the `account_tags` library is from [`django-user-accounts`](https://github.com/pinax/django-user-accounts). The [installation instructions](http://django-user-accounts.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) say that you should add `'account'` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting.